# how to update only one row in datagrid

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have a problem when i m run my code then updating is successful but I want to update only one row . when through my code all data is update .

My code is:

*Code*

```
protected void imgbtn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "update Companies set CompanyFName='" + txt_ComName.Text + "',CompanySName='" + txt_ShortName.Text + "',CompanyeMail='" + txt_email.Text + "',CompanyWebsite='" + txt_website.Text + "'where CompanyId=CompanyId";

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.UpdateCommand = cmd;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindGridData();
        lblError.Font.Bold = true;
        lblError.Font.Size = 11;
        lblError.Text = "You have successfully modified the case!";
    }
```

I don't know why?

Plz suggest me.

"Thanks"

Comment: Now sure if I understood the problem. Based on the code you are updating a record based on companyID. what makes you think that "all data is updated?"

Comment: yes but i want only as a company Id data is update.

Comment: what else is being updated and how come? you are not adding other data here which is visible so what else changes in your database?

Answer (score 0):

First use [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx). Check out this thread. [how to update a table using oledb parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters).

The problem with your code is that you are refreshing the complete data source using  `BindGridData();` There may be instances where other records are updated somewhere else in the code and it seems that your `BindGridData()` is getting data from the database again. You may store the existing data source in a temp location and then update it and bind it to the data grid instead of getting latest through db