# Syntax error in INSERT statement - C#, Access 2013, VS Express 2013

Tags: c#, insert, oledb, ms-access-2013

I have been trying to figure out why my program keeps giving me error. system.data.oledb.oledbexception(0x80040E14):  Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

- Table name: `User`
- Columns:

  ```
  Username
  AccountNumber
  FirstName
  LastName
  ```

Code:

```
namespace Library_System
{
    public partial class CreateAccountWindow : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data         Source=C:\Users\Jc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Library System\Library     System\LibrarySystemDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    //OleDbDataReader reader;

    public CreateAccountWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Username = "", AccountNumber = "", FirstName = "", LastName = "";
        //int Borrowed = 0;
        bool hasValue1 = false, hasValue2 = false, hasValue3 = false, hasValue4 = false;
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            label1.Hide();
            Username = textBox1.Text;
            hasValue1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Show();
            label1.Text = "Required";
        }

        if (textBox10.Text != "")
        {
            label21.Hide();

            AccountNumber = textBox8.Text;
            hasValue2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label21.Show();
            label21.Text = "Required";
        }

        if (textBox8.Text != "")
        {
            label13.Hide();

            FirstName = textBox10.Text;
            hasValue3 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label13.Show();
            label13.Text = "Required";
        }

        if (textBox7.Text != "")
        {
            label12.Hide();
            label12.Text = "Required";
            LastName = textBox7.Text;
            hasValue4 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label12.Show();
            label12.Text = "Required";
        }

        if (hasValue1 || hasValue2 || hasValue3 || hasValue4)
        {
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.CommandText = "insert into User (Username,AccountNumber,FirstName,LastName) values ('" + Username + "','" + AccountNumber + "','" + FirstName + "','" + LastName + "')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("REGISTRATION COMPLETE !!", "DONE");
                connect.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Error:"+ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Sorry but can you be more specific.  I have just started c# for 3 weeks.  I dont understand too technical terminologies

Comment: @JC Balantakbo, What is the ``AccountNumber`` field type?

Comment: @JCBalantakbo what marc_s meant was that you shouldn't create SQL queries by concatenating strings. For example if your Username was something like `a','b','c','d');drop table User;--` think what will be executed in the database. A malicious user might give that as a username to hack your system.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `USER` is a reserved word in Access SQL so you need to enclose the table name in square brackets. Also, as marc_s mentioned in a comment to the question, you should be using a parameterized query like this:

```csharp
// test data
string Username = "gord";
string AccountNumber = "gt001";
string FirstName = "Gord";
string LastName = "Thompson";

command.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO [User] (Username, AccountNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AccountNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", FirstName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", LastName);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a UNIQUE field as primary key.
[Fields that generate numbers automatically in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/fields-that-generate-numbers-automatically-in-access-HA001055067.aspx)

```
SelectCommand = "select @@IDENTITY";
var id = (int)SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with a primary key, and there's no reason why [Username] can't be the primary key for that table.

Comment: You should check it manually for replicate.You can not enter duplicate name in primary key fields.

Comment: Yes, but trying to insert a duplicate primary key value will not result in the "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" error cited in the question. Instead, such an action would trigger "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship."

Comment: @Gord Thompson, The correct syntax, I think that is the wrong data type.Maybe ``AccountNumber`` a numeric field.That it must be changed to a ``Text`` or ``Memo`` type.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run the insert query directly on db console? in your case its access. you might be having  some spelling mistake.
you have initialized oledbcommand object twice. you might not require to initialize it just after oledbconnection object.

also regarding the approach you can use the validators; check this link [How to: Validate Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707335(v=vs.91).aspx)

for oledbcommand parameters check below links:

[OleDBParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Update Data using OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters)

[Insert data using OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)