# SQL Update statement doesn't update values when adding multiple columns otherwise it does

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

No exceptions, everything gets executed but the update doesn't happen!

Everything works ok when I have just @JIR parameter but now I added @Paragon and the update doesn't do it's job. No exception whatsoever data passed is OK...

I don't see anything wrong with this query does anyone know what could possibly be going wrong?

```
private static void InsertJIR(FisDnevni racun)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(RegistarBlagajna.Modul.VezaNaBazu.ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"
                    UPDATE FisDnevni
                    SET [JIR] = @JIR, 
                    [Paragon] = @Paragon                                
                    WHERE BrojRacuna = @BrojRacuna"
                    , con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JIR", racun.JIR.Substring(0,37));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrojRacuna", racun.BrojRacuna);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paragon", racun.Paragon);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Try using `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`. Also, try to add the parameters in the same order as they appear in the query. (this shouldn't matter but can't hurt). Also, `OleDbCommand` is also an `IDisposable`, you should use it inside a `using` statement. One last thing - why are you using try...catch when all you do in your catch is `throw`?

Comment: Well, you're using different order when declaring parameters, try place `@Paragon` in second order instead.

Comment: @TetsuyYamamoto hmm I think that was it lol, you can post it as answer if you want me to accept it

Comment: @Zohar well damn I didn't know I had to write seperate using for Command too, write and answer if you want the me to accept it or do you want me to answer myself? xD...

Comment: So I understand the problem is solved then. I'll put together an answer later on. If I forget to do it within the next 24 hours, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update a table using oledb parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good old problem - ensure the query parameters in `OleDbParameter` are declared in proper order like this:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(RegistarBlagajna.Modul.VezaNaBazu.ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE FisDnevni SET [JIR] = @JIR, [Paragon] = @Paragon WHERE BrojRacuna = @BrojRacuna", con)
        {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JIR", racun.JIR.Substring(0,37));
             // this must be the second parameter instead of third one
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paragon", racun.Paragon);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrojRacuna", racun.BrojRacuna);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Note that [OLE DB .NET Provider doesn't recognize named parameters for `OleDbCommand` when CommandType is set to `Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), but it apparently does recognize the parameter order, hence as long as they're passed in proper order, it'll accepted as query parameter.

Related issue:

[how to update a table using oledb parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters)

Comment: Thank you I overlooked this, can't believe I wrote so many querys without paying attention to this and I got this far xD

Comment: Well, that's even better then the answer I was going to write, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i've just never used it, but why is there an @ here?

OleDbCommand(**@**"

i also havent worked with C# in a while but is multi-line concatenation possible without a + or something?

thirdly why are you using [] on these column names? i don't see any special characters or spaces.

this post is sounding a lot more dikkish than i mean it to be, im not trying, just legit curious

Comment: The wonders of writing querys in C#, when I put the @ sign in front of query I don't need concatenation with +... I'm using [ ] for nothing in perticular but aesthetics :D and to distinguish the column names (even though [] helps if you use column name similar to system name for example "time")...