# How to fix problem with textbox in Aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Hello I have an html registration form, I opened it with html and checked the data with javascript now I want to insert my data to access database and I don't know how to do it because it's making me problems...
I tried to write this aspx.cs :
`public void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Vort3eX\Desktop\RegisterDataBase.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into DataBase value('"+fname.Text+ 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }`

And I got this error :

> "The Name 'fname' does not exist the currect context"

My Html Code for my input

```html
   <tr>
            <td class="style4">
               Name
               </td>                
            <td class="style3">
           <input type="text"name="fname" id="fname" placeholder = "Name" />
            </td
        </tr>
```

Please help me to fix it I want to input data in my data access table...

Answer (score 1):

Your server-side code has no way of recognizing your HTML input without adding runat="server" to the input element:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="fname" placeholder="Name" runat="server" />
```

To access the value of a HTML element in the code-behind, you need to use:

```
fname.Value
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure there is a form element or nothing will be submitted:

http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp.html

You also need to be using query parameters in your code to avoid SQL Injection attacks:

[Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hey thank you for the trying to help, I added runat="server" and it still showing me this problem...

Comment: The property for the text is different with HTML inputs. I will update answer.

Comment: Cant i use OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Vort3eX\Desktop\RegisterDataBase.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters