# SYNTAX ERROR IN INSERT INTO statement pops in with OleDb unhandled when saving details with image in a table

Tags: c#, syntax-error, sql-insert, oledbexception

Am new to coding C# been trying to save some entered data in a form but keep getting  the systax error in insert into heres the code for the INSERT INTO
1.fields starting with txt are text boxes.
2.fields starting with cmb are combo boxes.
3. values with both double and single quotes are string data types
4.values with a double quote without single quotes are number data types

```
 string str = "Insert into tbl_member(F_Name, F_Gender, F_Contact, F_Email, F_Height, F_Weight, F_Batch, F_Member, F_Workout, F_Fee_Duration, F_Rec_No, F_Fee, F_Date, F_Day, F_Month, F_Year,F_Pic_prof) values('"+ txt_name.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + cmb_gender.Text + "','" + txt_contact.Text + "','" + txt_email.Text + "','"+ txt_height.Text + "','"+ txt_weight.Text + "','"+ cmb_batch.Text + "','"+ cmb_member.Text + "','"+ cmb_workout.Text + "','"+ cmb_fee_duration.Text + "','" + txt_rec_no.Text + "'," + txt_fee.Text + ",'"+ stdate + "'," + stday + "," + stmonth + "," + styear + ",'" + dest + "')";

            con = new OleDbConnection(scon);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = str;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted");
            Cleartext();
```

this is the entire code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Gym_Managment_System
{
    public partial class Add_member : Form
    {
        string scon = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Dragon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gym Managment System\Gym Managment System\Gym Management System.mdb;";
        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        int r;
        string ff_code;

        public Add_member()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Add_member_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'gym_Management_SystemDataSet.tbl_member' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tbl_memberTableAdapter.Fill(this.gym_Management_SystemDataSet.tbl_member);
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        }

        private void Cleartext()
        {
            txt_name.Text = "";
            cmb_gender.Text = "";
            txt_email.Text = "";
            txt_contact.Text = "";
            txt_height.Text = "";
            txt_weight.Text = "";
            cmb_batch.Text = "";
            cmb_member.Text = "";
            cmb_workout.Text = "";
            cmb_fee_duration.Text = "";
            txt_rec_no.Text = "";
            txt_fee.Text = "";
        }
        private void CompressImage(Image source, int imageQuality, string savePath)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create an imageCodecinfo-object for the cide information
                ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = null;

                //Set quality factor for compression
                EncoderParameter imageQualitysParameter = new EncoderParameter(
                                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, imageQuality);

                //List all available codecs (system wide)
                ImageCodecInfo[] alleCodecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

                EncoderParameters codecParameter = new EncoderParameters(1);
                int i=0;
                foreach (ImageCodecInfo jpegCodecs in alleCodecs )
                {
                    if (alleCodecs[i].MimeType == "Image/jpeg")
                    {
                        jpegCodec = alleCodecs[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
//        //Save compressed image
//        sourceImage.Save(savePath, jpegCodec, CodecParameter);
              }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //throw e;
            }
        }
    private void inserting()
        {
            string dest = "";

            if (txt_imagepath.Text != "")
            {

                //try
                //{
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(txt_imagepath.Text);
                string fileNameWithoutPath = info.Name;
                dest = Application.StartupPath + "\\Image\\" + fileNameWithoutPath;
                fileNameWithoutPath = info.Name;
                try// copy the image in your source folder image
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(txt_imagepath.Text, dest);
                }
                catch (Exception errr)
                { }
                CompressImage(Image.FromFile(dest), 30, dest);
                //catch (Exception errr)
                //{
                //     dest = "";
                //}
            }

                string stdate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
                string stday = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
                string stmonth = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
                string styear = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
            if (save.Text == "$Update")
            {
                string up = "update tbl_member set F_name='" + txt_name.Text.ToUpper() + "',F_Gender = '" + cmb_gender.Text + "',F_email = '" + txt_email.Text + "',F_Contact = '" + txt_contact.Text + "',F_Height = '" + txt_height.Text + "',F_Weight = '" + txt_weight.Text + "',F_Batch = '" + cmb_batch.Text + "',F_Member = '" + cmb_member.Text + "',F_Workout = '" + cmb_workout.Text + "',F_Fee_Duration = '" + cmb_fee_duration.Text + "',F_Rec_No = '" + txt_rec_no.Text + "',F_Fee = " + txt_fee.Text + ",F_Date = '" + stdate + "',F_Day = " + stday + ",F_Month = " + stmonth + ",F_Year = " + styear + ",F_Pic_prof'" + dest + "' where F_ID = " + ff_code + "";
                con = new OleDbConnection(scon);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = up;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Update is Successfully");
                save.Text = "&Save";
            } 
            else
            {
                string str = "insert into tbl_member (F_Name, F_Gender, F_Contact, F_Email, F_Height, F_Weight, F_Batch, F_Member, F_Workout, F_Fee_Duration, F_Rec_No, F_Fee, F_Date, F_Day, F_Month, F_Year,F_Pic_prof) values('" + txt_name.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + cmb_gender.Text + "','" + txt_contact.Text + "','" + txt_email.Text + "','" + txt_height.Text + "','" + txt_weight.Text + "','" + cmb_batch.Text + "','" + cmb_member.Text + "','" + cmb_workout.Text + "','" + cmb_fee_duration.Text + "','" + txt_rec_no.Text + "'," + txt_fee.Text + ",'" + stdate + "'," + stday + "," + stmonth + "," + styear + ",'" + dest + "')";

                con = new OleDbConnection(scon);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = str;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted");
            }

            Cleartext();
            funshow();
        }

        private void deleting()
        {

        }


        private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (dr.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                txt_imagepath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            pic_prof.Image = null;
            pic_prof.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pic_prof.Image = Image.FromFile(txt_imagepath.Text );

        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inserting();
        }

        private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        //for adjust grid view size
        private void viewadjust()
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 25;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "NAME";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "GENDER";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "CONTACT";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "EMAIL";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "HEIGHT";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "WEIGHT";
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "BATCH";
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "MEMBER";
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = "FEE_DURATION";
            dataGridView1.Columns[11].HeaderText = "REC_NO";
            dataGridView1.Columns[12].HeaderText = "FEE";
            dataGridView1.Columns[13].HeaderText = "DATE";
        }

        //for displat table data in grid view
        private void funshow()
        {

            string selectq = "";
            selectq = "select F_ID,F_Name, F_Gender, F_Contact, F_Email, F_Height, F_Weight, F_Batch, F_Member, F_Workout, F_Fee_Duration, F_Rec_No, F_Fee, F_Date, from tbl_member";
            con = new OleDbConnection(scon);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectq, con);

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
            viewadjust();
            totshow();
        }
        // for counting total records
        private void totshow()
        {
            int counting;
            int no1 = 0;
            counting = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            for (int k=0; k<counting; k++)
            {
                no1 = no1 + 1;
            }
            lbl_no.Text = "No of Records: " + no1.ToString();



        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            r = e.RowIndex;
        }

        private void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                int v1 = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                string na = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string delq = "Delete from tbl_member where F_ID" + v1 + "";
                con = new OleDbConnection(scon);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = delq;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Has Been Deleted Successfully( " + na.ToUpper() + " )");
                //, "Deleted", MessageBoxButton.OK. MessageButton.Infromation);

                Cleartext();
                funshow();
        }

        private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ff_code = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txt_name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            cmb_gender.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txt_email.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txt_contact.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txt_height.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            txt_weight.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            cmb_batch.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            cmb_member.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            cmb_workout.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            cmb_fee_duration.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            txt_rec_no.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            txt_fee.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[12].Value.ToString();

            save.Text = "&Update";
            txt_name.Focus();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void pic_prof_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

help me out

Comment: You need to [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/).

Comment: done that still not working

Comment: Please show *how* you used parameters, and the *exact* error message then. Parameters are *definitely* the way to go, for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about single quotes ( ' ) over txt_fee.Text .

So, the proper query will be like below (wrapped to multiple lines - easier to read):

```
string str = "Insert into tbl_member(F_Name   , F_Gender      , F_Contact, F_Email , " + 
                                    "F_Height , F_Weight      , F_Batch  , F_Member, " +
                                    "F_Workout, F_Fee_Duration, F_Rec_No , F_Fee   , " +
                                    "F_Date   , F_Day         , F_Month  , F_Year  , F_Pic_prof) " +
             "values('" + txt_name.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + cmb_gender.Text       + "'," + 
                    "'" + txt_contact.Text        + "','" + txt_email.Text        + "'," + 
                    "'" + txt_height.Text         + "','" + txt_weight.Text       + "'," + 
                    "'" + cmb_batch.Text          + "','" + cmb_member.Text       + "'," +
                    "'" + cmb_workout.Text        + "','" + cmb_fee_duration.Text + "'," +
                    "'" + txt_rec_no.Text         + "','" + txt_fee.Text          + "'," +
                    "'" + stdate + "'," + stday + "," + stmonth + "," + styear + ",'" + dest  + "')";
```

Comment: but the data type for txt.fee is number so i excluded it same with for stdate, stday, stmonth and styear.

Comment: 1.fields starting with txt are text boxes.
2.fields starting with cmb are combo boxes.
3. values with both double and single quotes are string data types
4.values with a double quote without single quotes are number data types

Comment: i have also tried adding thee single quotes to txt_fee but still notjhing