# Syntax error when clicking on submit button, I was having problems with my SQL Table so wondering if it might be linked

Tags: c#, web

I get this error when I click Submit on my registration form -

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'

Below is my code:

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table where UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text +"'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
    {
        Response.Write("User already Exists");
    }


    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Maybe enclose `Table` with `[]`.  Like so:  `[Table]`.  Probably not the best name for a table BTW

Comment: And what about if count is zero?

Comment: You need to [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/) before someone creates a user name like `Bobby'AND'0'='`. And `Table` is an SQL reserved word, you should create meaningful table names.

Comment: Ah yes, adding to Steve's fine comment - did you forget an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by MickyD and Dour High Arch, "Table" is a *reserved word* in SQL.

You can avoid the error by putting `Table` inside of square brackets (<kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>) in the query:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text +"'";
```

However, this isn't addressing the real problem - *design*. You have a table named `Table`.  You should strongly consider giving it a real name based on what it will be used for (e.g., "Students", "Sales", etc.).

### Security

Also, you have a *SQL injection vulnerability*.  You should look up what this means and how to parameterize a query.